# How to switch from a manual code to an automatic code of segmentation?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I use this code to extract from the image the delimitation between a homogeneous part of the image made of 0 of another part made mostly of 1.

I would like to know how to get automatic code. I can explain this: I find the delimitation in this case because I find manually where to place my mask (from column 500) `mask (:, 500: end)` but I want to find the value ' 500 ' automatically so that this code can be done whatever the image I give it.

So how can I automate the creation of my mask?

```
img=imread('imgage.png');
figure, imagesc(img), 

mask=false(size(img));
mask(:,480:end)=true;
seg = region_seg(img,mask,1000);
figure, imshow(seg);

SE =strel('disk',6);
D=imopen(seg,SE);
imwrite(seg, 'mask.tif')

bw=edge(D);
figure,imshow(bw)
```

Comment: Automatic image segmentation is a very very hot topic in the most advanced research in worldwide top tier universities. Whoever can answer this question can also become the next CEO of Google. 

Or.... You could show a bit more of your images so we might be able to find a trick. Your question, as it is right now, reminds me of [this](https://xkcd.com/1425/). Show us the type of images you have.

Comment: I edit the question with an image

Comment: here is :-) (green=1, black =0)

Comment: The red line is what I get with the code I show you. And the 480 I find it graphically with the scale given by imagesc and what I would like is to get this same line but finding the 480 automatically

Comment: It creates just two rectangleThe mask is only a white rectangle which will allow to make the delimitation with the function region_seg

Comment: hum ok, the region_seg function allows a segmentation with active contour (Van-Chese) (https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19567-active-contour-segmentation/content/regionbased_seg/region_seg.m) 
the line is in the left of the green thing

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: Almost. I lack of precision of the delimitation, but it's a great start. I'm working on it

Comment: You can always add/remove some indexes to the value that it gives. E.g. `indy=indy-10`

Comment: Yes of course but in this case it is always subjective, the -10 or +10 may be necessary for one image and not for another: - /

Comment: Then allways do -10 and you are safe. You can not have a general solution that works always. Thats not how it works!

Comment: No, because the delimitation of green part isn't always in the same place according to the image

Comment: But.... My code detects where the delimitation of green starts... Have you  tried it?... Anyway, I gave you a solution, good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by binarizing, eroding, dilating the image. This will create a "big blob" where there is information in the image, and where is not. You grab the first point where the information is, and *voila!*, there is you line.

```
img=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP973.png');

imgg=rgb2gray(img);
imgbw=im2bw(imgg,graythresh(imgg));

SE = strel('disk', 2, 4);
imgbw=imerode(imgbw,SE);
imgbw=imdilate(imgbw,SE);

[~,indy]=find(imgbw); %slow
indy=min(indy);
% just to show
hold on
imagesc([img]);axis ij; axis tight
plot([indy indy],[1,size(imgg,2)],'red')
```

[image]